# How to get Long 19 digits random numbers at PHP?

Tags: php, random, long-integer, uniqueidentifier

So I need to make unique purchase number of mobile game. Each user's buying of in-app-purchase item record should be attached by unique long type 19 digits numbers from php code and stored to mysql DB.

But how can I actually make random 19 digits numbers?

I tried like this but errors.

```
$num_str = sprintf("%19d", mt_rand(1, 9999999999999999999));
```

Comment: Warning: mt_rand(): max(-1981284352) is smaller than min(1) in E:\wamp\www\php1.php on line 3

Comment: you could concatenate rands: `$random = mt_rand(0,mt_getrandmax()).mt_rand(0,mt_getrandmax())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also try this:

```
function random19() {
  $number = "";
  for($i=0; $i<19; $i++) {
    $min = ($i == 0) ? 1:0;
    $number .= mt_rand($min,9);
  }
  return $number;
}

echo random19();
```

which would output some random 19 numbers: `6416113158912395605`

Comment: Can I change this to int or long type?

Comment: you can change it to int using typecast `(int)$var` or the `intval($var)` function but php's integer only handles 2^32 limit of numbers... it cannot reach 19 digits... hence the output would be like `2147483647`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like -

```
$num_str = sprintf("%10d", mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax())).sprintf("%9d", mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()));
if (strlen($num_str) < 19)
    $num_str = str_pad($num_str, 19, rand(0, 9), STR_PAD_RIGHT);
else if(strlen($num_str) > 19)
    $num_str = substr($num_str, 0, 19);
echo $num_str;
```

> The distribution of mt_rand() return values is biased towards even numbers on 64-bit builds of PHP when max is beyond 2^32. This is because if max is greater than the value returned by mt_getrandmax(), the output of the random number generator must be scaled up.

Comment: thx, but can I actually change this string to int or long value? and sometimes I get 18 digits, why and how can I make this to 19 digits?

Comment: or sometimes this produce 20 digits.

Comment: Updated the answer. Might help.

Comment: 10804566641431589031 : 20 digits

Comment: Thx, but what about 20 digits case?

Comment: This now can handle the both case.

Comment: But still sometimes 18 digits generated. 956075527263235884

Comment: There was typo in the `if` condition. change the variable name to `num_str`.

Comment: of course I knew and fixed, but still 18 digits. 714711512153330818

Comment: So there you wrote $num_str = sprintf("%8d", mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax())).sprintf("%8d", mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()));  but here 10, 9

Comment: No, but sometimes, it says 19, but actually value is 18 digits.   20 -> 19 -> 826323801192008355

Answer (score -1):

$randNumber = date("YmdHis").rand(11111,99999);

Comment: Always Create Unique Number

Comment: interesting kind of randomization using date... but I think there are more better ways of making random 19 digits than the date functionality...

Comment: Dear, Catzilla. Though you are not accepting my answer then tell me good answer.

Comment: Hi Vishal, your `date()` method is a valid form of randomization... yes, it is useful, but there are other functionalities in php that can handle random digits better... like `rand()` and  `mt_rand()` they are primarily designed to handle random digits... while `date()` is usually used for generating random dates.. and of course, I'm not sure but I guess the `m` cannot go beyond `12` and `d` cannot go beyond `31`, and `H` cannot go beyond `23` etc... there's a limitation using `date`... hope it helps... :)

Comment: This example may help people understand better the use of timestamps in random generated numbers or strings. Using a timestamp also helps prevent some rare possible collisions. I've seen SIMILAR methods in various applications, in manufacturing and also banking. +1 to Vishal